# How to dynamically access objects in ftl?

Tags: templates, yaml, freemarker

I have my data model stored in yaml as below

```
users:
  - "u1"
  - "u2"

u1:
  name: "user1"
  age: 25

u2:
  name: "user2"
  age: 26
```

I am trying to use the below template (ftl) to generate user records

```
[
    <#list users as user>
    {
        "username": "${${user}.name}"
        "userage": "${${user}.age}"
    },
    </#list>
]
```

my final output should look like:

```
[
    {
        "username": "user1",
        "userage": "25"
    },
    {
        "username": "user2",
        "userage": "26"
    }
]
```

How to achieve this? I am getting below error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is `.vars[user].name` (where `[]` does the lookup by a dynamic key, and `.vars` is a special variable to refer to all your top-level variables). Then you can put that whole thing into `${}` where that's needed.  You can also do `<#assign userObj = .vars[user]>`, and then later just write `userObj.name`, and `userObj.age`. (Though, regrading the name choices, I would use `userId` instead of `user`, and `user` instead of `userObj`.)

Last not least, the data-model should just be like this, if possible, and then everything is simpler, and less confusing:

```
users:
  u1:
    name: "user1"
    age: 25

  u2:
    name: "user2"
    age: 26
```

So then you can write something like `users.u1.age`. If the user ID is dynamic, and let's say it's in the `userId` variable, then you can write `users[userId].age`.